# php starup sqlsrv unable to initialize module

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am trying to connect MSSQL to PHP. i am following [this](http://davehiren.blogspot.com/2012/01/connect-with-microsoft-sql-server-from.html) tutorial. Anyway after i added the dll files as described in that tutorial, i get the following warning. How can i solve this ?

```
php starup sqlsrv unable to initialize module module compiled with module api=20090626 php compiled with module api=20020520 these options need to match
```

note:i have gone through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645483/php-startup-unable-to-initialize-module) but none helped.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like you've tried to install the sqlsrv extension for php 5.3 on a php 5.2 system.

Either run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and look for the php version and look for the following entries:

- PHP Version
- Thread Safety

pick the appropriate .dll from the sqlsrv driver: the version number must match and if thread safety is enabled pick the ts version, if not pick the nts version.

Comment: It's 5.4.4 and thread safety is enabled. From where could i get hold of the correct DLL ?

Comment: The tutorial you've linked to contains a link to the driver package. This pacakage contains a file php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll which sounds right.

Comment: Yes, after adding that i get the following error `This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86`. How can i solve this ?

Comment: By doing what the error message says. Download the native client and install it.

Comment: To reply on @lllep comment, you would need to download OCBC driver from: http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=36434 in case if you are using SQLSRV 3.1/3.2 for PHP5.5/5.6.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone trying to get it to work with PHP 5.5 (PHP    compiled with module API=20121212) then you can replace the dlls in the ext folder with new updated binaries [>here<](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e1d37219-88a3-46b2-a421-73bfa33fe433/unofficial-php-55-drivers-x86)

Don't forget to enable the new dlls in the php configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was with multiple php version under an Apache. The php cli loaded another php version's php.ini. The takeaway is: always check the configuration before you dig deeper into the problem.