# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\wamp\www\Webs\client.php on line 7

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

Am using windows 8 pro, Wamp server (php V5.3.5, apache V2.2.17), Sql server 2005 express editon. I have downloaded the sqlsrv drivers and extracted them into the php extention folder (`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\ext`), have also update the php.ini file by adding the extentions

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll
```

I used this two after series of try and error on all the dll file, it was this two that come up with no error, when restarting the wamp server

This is the connection line of code;

```
$con = sqlsrv_connect('TAQUATECH\SQLEXPRESS') or die("cannot connect");
```

It came up with the following error;

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in
>   C:\wamp\www\Webs\client.php on line 7

pls, i need somebody to help me on this, i will really appreciate

Comment: If you can't see the startup errors, have the a look at the Apache logs.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if too late to answer, but I had the same error, and I found out that Wamp Server 64bit does not support SQL Server Connection, you must install a 32bit version of wamp server.

Answer (score 1):

For those using 64-bit systems (OS, WAMP, MSSQL), these 64-bit drivers can serve them and fix the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\wamp\www...

Drivers SQLSRV x64:

http://robsphp.blogspot.in/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install and enable sqlsrv on your web server. Have a look at the [installation page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php) on the official PHP website.

Comment: Thanks have looked at the installation page, Under the requirement in Microsoft site, window 8 is not included, could that be the problem?, because am using window 8 os

Answer (score 0):

[**Installation**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=20098) of Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server will fix this issue. Also try this [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php).

**EDIT :**

> The most recent version of the driver is available for download here:
>   » SQLSRV 3.0 download. If you need support for PHP 5.2 and/or PHP
>   compiled with VC6, use the 2.0 release of the driver: » SQLSRV 2.0
>   download.

**[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx)**

Comment: thnks for your reply, but have done the installation before have even install the 2.0 version with it

Comment: You need 3.0 as you are using php 5.3.5

Comment: I edited the php.ini to use the 3.0 dll file, when i restarted the wamp server, it displays a warning message
    PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module
    Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC9
    PHP compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC6
    These options need to match

Comment: Please go through this link. Exactly the same problem what you are facing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154738/php-starup-sqlsrv-unable-to-initialize-module

Comment: I used 
    extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll
    extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll
The server starts successfully
but still cant identify the function "sqlsrv_connect()" - same undifined error message

Comment: am using windows 8, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yap, I have gotten a work-around;
The problem was, running the php script using apache server on my system, I stoped the wamp server and configure fastCGI for PHP using IIS 7, You can get a video tutorial Here

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-php-applications-on-iis/set-up-fastcgi-for-php.

It simple and nice, now i can connect to both sql server 2005 and 2008

**My PHP Details**

Version => 5.3.5
Compiler => MSVC6 (Visual C++ 6.0) 
SqlSrv Driver => php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll

Answer (score 0):

```
use 32 bit PHP Version.
enable below one of them in php.ini
[PHP_PDO_SQLSRV_53_NTS]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
[PHP_SQLSRV_54_NTS]
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
[PHP_SQLSRV_53_NTS]
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
[PHP_PDO_SQLSRV_54_NTS]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll



thease dll version you can downlowd online
```