# Unable to Connect SQL Server with PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, apache, codeigniter

I am trying to connect SQL Server Database with PHP Codeigniter by following this [guide](https://futbolsalas15.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/7-steps-to-make-sql-server-and-codeigniter-works/)  and using latest SQLSRV3.0 Files , My PHP Version is 5.6.3 and Thread Safety is enabled however on starting the apace I am getting following error:

> PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module Module compiled with
>   module API=20100525 PHP compiled with module API=20131226 these
>   options need to match.

How can I fix the problem now and whats the way to match both APIs?

Comment: you see that question? I think you can help. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154738/php-starup-sqlsrv-unable-to-initialize-module

Answer (score 0):

SQLSRV 3.0 was released on 2012 and it doesn't support PHP/5.6, which was released on 2014. The *SQLSRV_Readme.htm* file in the package clearly explains the versions supported by each DLL but the mere absence of a php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll file is an indication that something's wrong. The minimum version you need is SQLSRV 3.2 (so far it's also the maximum version because SQLSRV 4.x requires PHP/7).

You can find detailed version information in the [official download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) (scroll down and expand the *System Requirements* section).